# How to stop a specific whatsapp chat from using mobile data?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, 3g, chat, spam

I'm on a computer science course, and a few of my peers made a whatsapp group for anybody on the course to join.

There are about 100 or so people in the group, and often I "lurk" on it to get help on various topics since there is sometimes some actual useful information disclosed. However, the group admins and some of their friends use the group as though they're the only ones there, meaning there's so much spam of simple idle "banter" that it actually drains my mobile data.

I also use whatsapp to message other groups or friends, so I don't want deny whatsapp as a whole of using my mobile data.

Is there a way to make a group only "receive" messages when connected via wifi?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately  NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good requirement but unfortunately Whatsapp didn't have such a settings.

If you want to avoid getting notifications, you can **Mute** the group.

But here, your requirement is different.

So, First understand how the blocking works.

1. It works by the way we are blocking any access to the particular host from our phone. That means, no request, no response.
2. Here, whatsapp use same host for all messages, you can't block it.

If whatsapp use different host for different chat , there is no problem. But here it is not the case.

**So, either you can block entire whatsapp or you can't block anything at all**